# Should the FAQ encourage copy and pasting code for questions?

Tags: feature-request, code, faq-update-request

A couple of times I've seen questions where the code snippets supplied in the question don't exhibit the problem asked about in the question - such as the original version of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/9403768/1). Sometimes this is because the code has been accidentally corrected by the author when they copied out their code snippets by hand (as it was in this case).

Copying and pasting the snippet would have avoided the automatic correction and would save time for the asker and people trying to answer the question. Should the "how to ask a question" bit of the FAQ encourage copying and pasting code where possible?

Comment: ...perhaps with a link to http://sscce.org/?

Comment: I don't expect it would help, but I support this.

Comment: From the title, I thought this was about not posting screenshots of code, which I see occasionally and which drives me half mad. There's also the "I changed this to dummy code" "Well, the dummy code doesn't make sense/exhibit the problem/even compile." I think including this in How To Ask is a fine idea.

Comment: This is a great first step. Now, if we could only get those people to read the FAQ...

Comment: @TheEstablishment (a) still, no reason not to update the FAQ (and the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) page); but (b) in the spirit of your observation, we should update the [Ask Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) form, too.